# Issue while continuously setting label text on locale change

Tags: user-interface, javafx, label, javafx-8, scenebuilder

In my JavaFX application, user can choose either English or Hindi language for display purpose. If I am continually switching between English and Hindi languages, at one stage, spaces or special characters in Hindi text are replaced by some horizontal lines as shown in the screenshot. 
I have tried setting label text in separate thread, but no use.
Is it due to caching issue? I tried to clear label text before setting it, but still facing same issue. Also, cache property of label is disabled. Any suggestions?

I am referring 'I18N utility class' from blog [Link][1]. This class sets the locale whenever language is selected by user and triggers `textproperty()` of labels.

And here is the snippet of code:

```
public class example implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Label dateLbl;

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
          engBtn.setOnAction((evt) -> switchLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH));
          hnBtn.setOnAction((evt) -> switchLanguage(new Locale("hi","IN")));
          dateLbl.textProperty().bind(createStringBinding(() ->
              I18N.changeDate())); //DATE LABEL WHICH IS SHOWING WEIRD BEHAVIOUR
     }

     private void switchLanguage(Locale locale) {
         I18N.setLocale(locale);
     }
```

///////////////////
class i18N:
////////////////

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;


public final class i18N {
    /** the current selected Locale. */
    private static final ObjectProperty<Locale> locale;
    static {
        locale = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(getDefaultLocale());
        locale.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> Locale.setDefault(newValue));
    }

    /**
     * get the supported Locales.
     *
     * @return List of Locale objects.
     */
    public static List<Locale> getSupportedLocales() {  
return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Locale.ENGLISH, new Locale("hi","IN")));        
//return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Locale.ENGLISH, new Locale("hi","IN")));
    }

    /**
     * get the default locale. This is the systems default if contained in the supported locales, english otherwise.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static Locale getDefaultLocale() {
        Locale sysDefault = Locale.getDefault();
        return getSupportedLocales().contains(sysDefault) ? sysDefault : Locale.ENGLISH;
    }

    public static Locale getLocale() {
        return locale.get();
    }

    public static void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        localeProperty().set(locale);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
    }

    public static ObjectProperty<Locale> localeProperty() {
        return locale;
    }

    /**
     * gets the string with the given key from the resource bundle for the current locale and uses it as first argument
     * to MessageFormat.format, passing in the optional args and returning the result.
     *
     * @param key
     *         message key
     * @param args
     *         optional arguments for the message
     * @return localized formatted string
     */
    public static String get(final String key, final Object... args) {
        /*temp++;
        if(temp%2==0){
        }
        else {

        }*/
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.lang", getLocale());
        return MessageFormat.format(bundle.getString(key), args);
    }


     public static String changeDate() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

         SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
         dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy E HH:mm a",getLocale());
         Date date = new Date();
         System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
         return dateFormat.format(date);

    }

    /**
     * creates a String binding to a localized String for the given message bundle key
     *
     * @param key
     *         key
     * @return String binding
     */
    public static StringBinding createStringBinding(final String key, Object... args) {
        return Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> get(key, args), locale);
    }

    /**
     * creates a String Binding to a localized String that is computed by calling the given func
     *
     * @param func
     *         function called on every change
     * @return StringBinding
     */
    public static StringBinding createStringBinding(Callable<String> func) {
        return Bindings.createStringBinding(func, locale);
    }

    /**
     * creates a bound Label whose value is computed on language change.
     *
     * @param func
     *         the function to compute the value
     * @return Label
     */
    public static Label labelForValue(Callable<String> func) {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(createStringBinding(func));
        return label;
    }

    /**
     * creates a bound Button for the given resourcebundle key
     *
     * @param key
     *         ResourceBundle key
     * @param args
     *         optional arguments for the message
     * @return Button
     */
    public static Button buttonForKey(final String key, final Object... args) {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.textProperty().bind(createStringBinding(key, args));
        return button;
    }

    /**
     * creates a bound Tooltip for the given resourcebundle key
     *
     * @param key
     *         ResourceBundle key
     * @param args
     *         optional arguments for the message
     * @return Label
     */
    public static Tooltip tooltipForKey(final String key, final Object... args) {
        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
        tooltip.textProperty().bind(createStringBinding(key, args));
        return tooltip;
    }

}
```

![Screenshot][2]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you illustrate.

Comment: @trashgod..Thnx for your suggestion...i have added code for reference

Comment: @trashgod... I have also added the java file which i am using for Dynamic change...Any suggestions now?
If I replace hindi by different languages (germa,chinese,japanese),I am not facing any such issue with them..

Comment: also if i use textfield instead of label, issue does not occur...But I don't want to use textfields in place of labels...

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed:

Current fontstyle was causing error.. I changed it to 'Arial' fontstyle now it is working properly :)